# Question about trigonometric functions in the space complex.

Tags: geometry

I have a question: 
Why in the complex plane don't have a sense of geometric definitions of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but we do have a sense of what the trigonometric functions are in the complex plane, see this diagram:

$\phantom{X}\;\;$[image: diagram made by your humble correspondent Hakim ;-)]